# Should I use qAsConst on QHash::keys() in a C++11 range-based for

Tags: qt, c++11, qhash

In this article [*Goodbye, Q_FOREACH*](https://www.kdab.com/goodbye-q_foreach/) from KDAB, they warn that a range-based `for` could cause a detach of a Qt container.
See also here : [Using C++11 range-based for loop correctly in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35811053/6165833)

I understand that the `for` will cause a detach because it is calling some non-const iterators if the container is not const.
Is it the same for the `QHash::keys()` return value ?
The `keys()` function is const so my map will not detach, but the return value is passed by value so will I copy the QList twice ?

Then, should I loop like this ?

```
for(auto key : qAsConst(map.keys())) {
    // do something with key or map.value(key)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not even compile (Qt5.9 - MSVC 2015) :

```
QMap<QString, int> map;
for(auto key : qAsConst(map.keys())) {
    // do something with key or map.value(key)
}
```

> error: use of deleted function 'void qAsConst(const T&&) [with T =
>   QList]'

Comment: The function is deleted for rvalue due to (possible) ownership issues. As stated in the article you can simple assign the rvalue to a const variable i.e. `auto const keys = map.keys()` and then use that in the range for.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a temporary keys() container just to iterate over it, is a really slow solution anyway. Prefer using iterators instead.