# c++11 range-loop might detach Qt container

Tags: qt, c++11

Using Qt Creator to edit C++11 code for the MinGW build kit.

Each time we iterate over a Qt container it gives this warning:

[image: Loop through Qt object]

Is there a better way to write this which doesn't trigger the warning?

[Using C++11 range-based for loop correctly in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811053/using-c11-range-based-for-loop-correctly-in-qt) **is not an answer - please don't mark as duplicate!**  This question suggests to use qAsConst; however this doesn't seem to help:

```
for (const QString &field : qAsConst(fields.keys()))
// - "Call to deleted function qAsConst"

for (const QString &field : qAsConst(fields).keys())
// - no effect, obviously - it was already const

for (const QString &field : std::as_const(fields.keys()))
// - "Call to deleted function as_const"

for (QJsonObject::const_iterator field = fields.constBegin(); field != fields.constEnd(); ++field)
// works, but a bit long-winded
```

Comment: The code is bad in two ways - first it creates a temporary container by iterating over the `fields` and then the operation on this temporary is not const so detach() is called for every iteration. Use plain iterators instead.