# What is a "container detachement" in the C++11 ranged based loop over QList? Is it a performance only problem?

Tags: c++, qt, foreach, copy-on-write

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811053/using-c11-range-based-for-loop-correctly-in-qt) contains some proposals for working around the problem, I would like to understand more in depth that exactly the problem is:

```
 QList<QString> q;
 for (QString &x: q) { .. }
```

1. Is it so that unless the container is declared `const`, Qt makes a
   copy of the list and then iterates over that copy? This is not among
   the best, but would be bearable if the list is small (say 10-20
   QString's).
2. Is it performance only problem or it can be some deeper
   problem? Let's assume we do not add/remove elements while the loop is running.
3. Is the modification of the value in the loop (assuming it is
   a reference) something that still works or it is fundamentally
   broken?

Comment: I use a range based for loop all the time in Qt. I will have to watch the video soon to attempt to understand the issue. In my case I doubt it is a significant problem since most of the time a container has a few items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Copy-on-write (=Implicit sharing) concept

It is important to understand that [copy-on-write (= implicit shared)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#implicit-sharing-iterator-problem) classes externally behaves like "normal" classes that perform a deep copy of their data. They only postpone this (potentially) expensive copy operation as long as possible. A deep copy is made (=detaching), only if the following sequence occurs:

- The list is implicitly shared, i.e. the object is copied by value (and at least 2 instances still exist)
- A non-const member function is accessed on the implicitly shared object.

#### Your questions

1. **Only if the container is shared** (by another copy on write instance of this list), **a copy of the list will be made** (as a non-const member is invoked on the list object). Note that the C++ range loop is just a short hand for a normal iterator based for loop (see [[1]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for the exact equivalence which depends on the exactly used C++ version):

   ```
   for (QList<QString>::iterator& it = q.begin(); x != q.end(); ++it)
   {
       QString &x = *it;
       ...
   }
   ```

   Note that the `begin` method is a const member function if and only if the list `q` itself is declared const. If you would write it in full yourself, you should use `constBegin` and `constEnd` instead.

   So,

   ```
   QList<QString> q;
   q.resize(10);
   QList<QString>& q2 = q; // holds a reference to the same list instance. Modifying q, also modifies q2.
   for (QString &x: q) { .. }
   ```

   doesn't perform any copy, as list `q` isn't implicitly shared with another instance.

   However,

   ```
   QList<QString> q;
   q.resize(10);
   QList<QString> q2 = q; // Copy-on-write: Now q and q2 are implicitly shared. Modifying q, doesn't modify q2. Currently, no copy is made yet.
   for (QString &x: q) { .. }
   ```

   does make a copy of the data.
2. **This is mostly a performance issue**. Only if the list contain some special type with a **weird copy constructor/operator**, this may be not the case, but this would probably indicate a bad design. In rare cases, you may also encounter the [Implicit sharing iterator problem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#implicit-sharing-iterator-problem), by detaching (i.e. deep copy) a list when an iterator is still active.

   Therefore, it is good practice to avoid unneeded copies in all circumstances by writing:

   ```
   QList<QString> q = ...;
   for (QString &x: qAsConst(q)) { .. }
   ```

   or

   ```
   const QList<QString> q = ...;
   for (QString &x: q) { .. }
   ```
3. **Modifications in the loop aren't broken and work as expected**, i.e. they behave as if the `QList` doesn't use implicit sharing, but performs a deep copy during a copy constructor/operator. For example,

   ```
   QList<QString> q;
   q.resize(10);
   QList<QString>& q2 = q;
   QList<QString> q3 = q;
   for (QString &x: q) {x = "TEST";}
   ```

   `q` and `q2` are identical, all containing 10 times "TEST". `q3` is a different list, containing 10 empty (null) strings.

Also check the Qt documentation itself about [Implicit Sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), which is used extensively by Qt. In modern C++, this performance optimization construct could be (partially) replaced by newly introduced move concept.

#### Improve understanding by inspecting source code

Every non-const function calls `detach`, before actually modifying the data, f.ex. [[2]](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h.html#_ZN5QList5beginEv):

```
inline iterator begin() { detach(); return reinterpret_cast<Node *>(p.begin()); }
inline const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<Node *>(p.begin()); }
inline const_iterator constBegin() const noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<Node *>(p.begin()); }
```

However, `detach` only effectively detaches/deep copy the data when the list is actually shared [[3]](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h.html#_ZN5QList6detachEv):

```
inline void detach() { if (d->ref.isShared()) detach_helper(); }
```

and `isShared` is implemented as follows [[4]](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qrefcount.h.html#_ZNK9QtPrivate8RefCount8isSharedEv):

```
bool isShared() const noexcept
{
    int count = atomic.loadRelaxed();
    return (count != 1) && (count != 0);
}
```

i.e. more than 1 copy (= another copy except for the object itself) exists.